# Can't call function from body onload (uncaught reference error: resetLoginForm is not defined) javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a body onload calling a function in javascript. I Have tried many things, but the console just prints to the error log:

> uncaught reference error: resetLoginForm is not defined

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

    <head>

        <title>Login Page</title>

        <script src="/client/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/client/js/querystring.js"></script>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--Import materialize.css-->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <script type="module" src="js/login.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body class="blue-grey darken-2" onload="resetLoginForm()">

        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

This is the JavaScript code that I am trying to use:

```
import * as Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js";

function resetLoginForm() {

    if (Cookies.get("destination") === undefined) {
        window.location.href = "/client/index.html";
    }

    const loginForm = $('#loginForm');
    loginForm.submit(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: loginForm.serialize(),
            success: response => {
                if (response.startsWith('Error:')) {
                    alert(response);
                } else {
                    Cookies.set("sessionToken", response);
                    window.location.href = Cookies.get("destination");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The HTML seems to be missing the forms with those ids. And which script name loads the above JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using new ECMAScript modules (`<script type="module" ...>`), which are isolated to their own scope. Your function `resetLoginForm()` isn't being defined in the global scope (Where you can essentially call it from your onload body function). You need to define it explicitly in your module:

```
import * as Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js";

window.resetLoginForm = {

    if (Cookies.get("destination") === undefined) {
        window.location.href = "/client/index.html";
    }
    ...
```

**Ideally though**, you should not be using `onload` at all. Just add an event listener in:

```
import * as Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js";

function resetLoginForm() {

    if (Cookies.get("destination") === undefined) {
        window.location.href = "/client/index.html";
    }

    ...
}

// Attach an event, and call resetLoginForm when the document is done loading.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resetLoginForm);
```

Comment: So I added the event listener. The import * as Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js"; gives an error saying login.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cookies.get is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.resetLoginForm (login.js:5)      so when I changed the import to  import Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js"; it now gives an error saying The requested module '/client/js/js.cookie.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: @MarleyPowell Well that's another error all together. `console.log(Cookies)`. Does `/client/js/js.cookie.min.js` exist?

Comment: console.log(Cookies) returns some values

Comment: What is that file? Is it a library? `console.log(Cookies.get)`: Is it a function?

Comment: console.log(Cookies.get)
ƒ (e){return C.call(C,e)} . I'm using this: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: I have no clue. It's showing a function: So `Cookies.get()` shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: `The requested module '/client/js/js.cookie.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` Thats what happens when I change the import to `import Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js";`

Comment: It should be `import * as Cookies from "/client/js/js.cookie.min.js"`

Comment: I'm using intellij and is says `Unresolved function or method get()`

Comment: IDK if itellij is smart enough to import via absolute paths (ie. `/client/js`) to know to look in your project folder.

Comment: I changed the path and the get() error disappeared but now there's another error `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/ComputerScienceProject/resources/client/js/js.cookie.min.js`

Comment: @MarleyPowell All these errors are sadly unrelated to the question posted. I recommend either posting a new question, or digging into this more yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change is `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>`
2. Cnages is  please check once `resetLoginForm` function in onload.

Comment: Will `import` statements work without having `type="module"` defined?