# Calling function defined in module not in scope for onload

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with modules/scope. I need to declare script tags as type="module" but then functions declared in that scope are not global, so can't be called with onload etc.

First file: index.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="module">
  import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';
  function x() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    myDiv.innerHTML = sayHi('John')
  }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="x()">
  <div id="myDiv"> *** replace with function call *** </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Second file: sayHi.js

```
export function sayHi(user) {
  return (`Hello, ${user}!`);
}
```

The x function is not in scope outside of the  block, so I get the error:

```
(index):36 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
    at onload ((index):36)
```

How do I make x global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that's how modules work:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

> Last but not least, let's make this clear — module features are
> imported into the scope of a single script — they aren't available in
> the global scope. Therefore, you will only be able to access imported
> features in the script they are imported into, and you won't be able
> to access them from the JavaScript console, for example. You'll still
> get syntax errors shown in the DevTools, but you'll not be able to use
> some of the debugging techniques you might have expected to use.

But [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950799/cant-call-function-from-body-onload-uncaught-reference-error-resetloginform-i) should provide you with a workaround:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="module">
  import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';
  function x() {
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    myDiv.innerHTML = sayHi('John')
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", x);
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"> *** replace with function call *** </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to create global variables from a module script, there is likely no need for this in your situation.

Since the evaluation of module scripts is automatically deferred, you can directly access the element in the script:

```
<script type="module">
  import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  myDiv.innerHTML = sayHi('John')
</script>
```

If this doesn't work for you for whatever reason, bind an event handler from inside the script instead:

```
<script type="module">
  import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
   myDiv.innerHTML = sayHi('John')
  });
</script>
```